# Parsing {% trans %}{{employee.title}}{% endtrans %} throws an error

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

Folks,

Parsing `{% trans %}{{employee.title}}{% endtrans %}` throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/src/employee/frontend/views.py", line 38, in get
    tpl = jinja2_env.get_template('index.html')
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py", line 127, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 493, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source)
  File "/Users/john/src/employee/frontend/templates/index.html", line 26, in template
    {% trans %}{{employee.title}}{% endtrans %}
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '.'
```

Parsing `{% trans %}Software Engineer{% endtrans %}` works well, any thoughts?

Update: Now it's not throwing an error, but it's not translating, this is the code snippet:

`{% for employee in employees %}
    <li class="employee">
        <div>
            {% trans title=employee.title %}{{title}}{% endtrans %}
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Do you already have translated content for that title?

Comment: Yes, I do, it works if I hardcode the translatable string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has 2 prongs.  If you need help internationalizing your webpage to get it ready to translate information it you can use rules like this:

If you have static information on the webpage use `{% trans %} Title {% endtrans %}`.

If you would rather, you can translate dynamic text before it is put in the template using the gettext library.

the commmon usage is something like this:

```
from webapp2_extras.i18n import gettext as _
params['title']=_("My Translated Title Method")
self.render_template('my.html',**params)
```

and render the text using the `{{title}}` syntax in your template.
docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html

the 2nd prong is Localization and that has to do with running babel your text files you set up in order to translate the local language (english I'm assuming) to the foreign language.
check out http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.9/intro.html for more.

Comment: I don't want to traverse the employees dataset twice, do you know why `{% trans title=employee.title %}{{title}}{% endtrans %}` is not working?

Comment: You don't have to traverse it more times.  the {{title}} in your template is just to place the already translated text.  As for the topic question,  Are you sure you have an attribute title in employee? (to make employee.title) the error makes it sound like employee doesn't have attributes.

Comment: You do, it's a collection of employees, I would have to traverse the collection and use gettext to get the translations and then pass the result to the template and then the template would have to traverse result again.

Comment: in your template you don't wrap it in {% trans %} {{Title}} {% endtrans %}     just {{Title}}

Comment: I know but you need to traverse the employees dataset twice, once to translate the content and second one to render the result, there should be a better way to fix this issue.

Comment: I'll approve your answer, it's not the ideal solution but it gets the work done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the property to a variable to use it inside trans:

```
{% trans title=employee.title %}{{ title }}{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: That took care of the error but it's not translating, any idea?

Comment: Any thought on this?, I haven't been able to translate the content.